# LINQ Select projection and different subtypes

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out how to use LINQ .Select and project into a new List of a subtype class.
The following method works for me but I would like the code to be a bit cleaner and not have the repeated object initialization code which is identical for both types.

Basically, if a boolean condition is true I want to return a List of 1 subclass, and if it's not return the other subclass.  The method signature uses IEnumerable and is working correctly.

Is there a recommended way to dynamically create the new subclass inside the select at runtime with a particular subclass type so that the object initialization can only be declared once? I have tried several approaches but can't seem to find the correct syntax - eg. I thought I could perhaps get the Type and use the Activator to instantiate the subclass right inside the LINQ .Select but don't know if that is possible.

```
private IEnumerable<BaseType> GetSubTypeList(IEnumerable<AnotherClass> sourceList, bool myCondition)
{
    if (myCondition)
    {
         return sourceList.Select(
             wc => new SubType1
             {
                 Field1 = "Field 1",
                 Field2 = "Field 2"
             }).ToList();
    }
    return sourceList.Select(
        wc => new SubType2
        {
            Field1 = "Field 1",
            Field2 = "Field 2"
        }).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: Do the types have a common ancessor that defines the properties (interface or parent class)?  If not this is the best you can do.  Otherwise you can separate the creation and element setting into separate steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will mark this as answered - came up with a solution although it doesn't exactly fully answer my question.  I specifically wanted to know if there was a way to achieve this right inside the LINQ .Select and object initialization.

But I succeeded in cleaning up the duplication using a combination of Nafis Islam's answer to move the object initialization and assignment into a helper function and then by creating each object in the list using it's Type and the Activator class.

Here is what I came up with:

```
private IEnumerable<BaseClass> GetSubTypeList(IEnumerable<AnotherClass> sourceList, bool myCondition)
{
  return sourceList.Select(sl => 
         GetSubType(myCondition, sl.Field1, sl.Field2)).ToList();
}

private BaseClass GetSubType(bool myCondition, string field1, string field2)
{
   var type = myCondition ? typeof(SubType1) : typeof(SubType2);
   var item = (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   item.Field1 = "Field 1";
   item.Field2 = "Field 2";
   return item;
}
```

The returned list will now be the type of the correct subclass, and the object initialization is not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
private IEnumerable<BaseType> GetSubTypeList(IEnumerable<AnotherClass> sourceList, bool myCondition) =>
  sourceList.Select(sl => GetSubType(myCondition, "Field 1", "Field 2"));

private BaseType GetSubType(bool myCondition, string a, string b) =>
  myCondition
  ? new SubType1 { Field1 = a, Field2 = b }}
  : new SubType2 { Field1 = a, Field2 = b }}
```

Comment: Thanks - this does make the select a bit cleaner by moving the initialization duplication into a helper method.  I thought that there might be a way to dynamically figure out the type at runtime and instantiate the new List of type - but haven't been able to find a way to do that yet (it it is even possible)

Comment: Thanks Nafis - see my answer below